# I can not understand what is this syntax error in my SQL trigger function (Postgres SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I received this syntax error in Postgres SQL

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 41: end;
            ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1807
```

Far as I know, this "end" is correct in syntax
I cannot understand what wrong here?
Can anyone help me figure it out?
Here are my SQL queries in Postgres SQL

```
--Trigger update ave_imported_price after insert, update, delete in invoice_item 
    --create a view (item_id, total_imported_quantity) for later use
create or replace view item_with_quantity as
select item_id, sum(ii2.quantity) as qty 
from item i2 inner join invoice_item ii2 using(item_id)
        inner join item_order io using(item_id) 
where i2.state = 1
group by (item_id);

    --trigger function
create or replace function func_update_ave_imported_price_when_change_invoice_item() returns trigger as
$$ declare
    var_qty int; --total qty
begin
    if TG_OP = 'insert' then
        select qty into var_qty from item_with_quantity where item_id = new.item_id;
        -- update ave_imported_price
        -- new_ave_price = ((old_total_qty*old_ave_price)+ (new.qty*new.imported_price)) / new_total_qty
        update item set ave_imported_price = ((var_qty*ave_imported_price) 
                + (new.quantity*new.imported_price)) / (var_qty + new.quantity)
            where item.item_id = new.item_id;
        return new;
        
    else if TG_OP = 'update' then
        select qty into var_qty from item_with_quantity where item_id = new.item_id;
        -- update ave_imported_price
        -- updated_ave_price = ((old_total_qty*old_ave_price) - (old.qty*old.imported_price)
        --  + (new.qty*new.imported_price)) / (old_total_qty - old.qty + new.qty)
        update item set ave_imported_price = ((var_qty*ave_imported_price) - (old.quantity*old.imported_price) 
                + (new.quantity*new.imported_price)) / (var_qty - old.quantity + new.quantity)
            where item.item_id = new.item_id;
        return new;
        
    else if TG_OP = 'elete' then
        select qty into var_qty from item_with_quantity where item_id = new.item_id;
        -- update ave_imported_price
        -- ave_price = ((old_total_qty*old_ave_price) - (old.qty*old.imported_price)) / new_total_qty
        update item set ave_imported_price = ((var_qty*ave_imported_price) 
                - (old.quantity*old.imported_price)) / (var_qty - old.quantity)
            where item.item_id = new.item_id;
        return old;
    end if;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) it's `elsif` not `else if`

Comment: "else if TG_OP = 'update'" will be 'delete'. I have fixed it but still received error

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh! thank you, it works. sorry for my stupid question :((

Comment: TG_OP = 'elete'... That should be "delete" with a d.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name.  Just to be clear `elseif`, no space, is also acceptable.